# SQL local lookup list

Tags: sql, list, local

Is it possible to make a local lookup list in the sql query?

Somthing like this

```
SELECT ID from table
  (select o.number from o join ID = o.id)



Local list as o
ID, Number
x = 1
y = 2
z = 3
```

Comment: Describe what you have (sample table data), and what you want.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't stated which database product you are using, so this is standard ANSI SQL:

```
select *
from the_table t
  join ( 
     values ('x', 1), ('y', 2) ('z',3) 
  ) as o (id,number) on t.id = o.id;
```

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what i was looking for.